# My Swi-prolog code return true for every query

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write Swi-Prolog code for family relations. There are no error but it always returns true. P

```
man(_Pete).
man(_Mark).
man(_John).
man(_Frank).
man(_Tom).
man(_Matt).
man(_Henry).
man(_Todd).
woman(_Lilly).
woman(_Kate).
woman(_Anne).
woman(_Alice).
woman(_Jenny).

parent(_Pete,_Mark).
parent(_Pete,_Tom).
parent(_Pete,_Anne).
parent(_Mark,_Lilly).
parent(_Mark,_John).
parent(_Mark,_Frank).
parent(_Tom,_Kate).
parent(_Anne,_Alice).
parent(_Anne,_Matt).
parent(_Alice,_Henry).
parent(_Matt,_Jenny).
parent(_Matt,_Todd).


father(X,Y) :- man(X),parent(X,Y).
mother(X,Y) :- woman(X),parent(X,Y).
sibling(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).
sister(X,Y) :- woman(X),sibling(X,Y).
brother(X,Y) :- man(X), sibling(X,Y).
grandparent(X,Y) :- parent(X,Z),parent(Z,Y).
```

I'm expecting to check relations. Like if I try a function ?- parent(Pete,John). I believe it should return false, but it actually returns true for every query. This is my first program on Prolog and might need help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to write names but instead you put *anonymous variables* in there.

Instead of `parent(_Matt,_Todd)` you should write `parent('Matt', 'Todd')` or even `parent(matt, todd)`.

- This is an anonymous variable: `_X`.
- This is a normal variable: `X`.
- This is a lower-case atom. It is has a length of 1, so it is also a "char": `x`.
- This is an upper-case char: `'X'`.

If you wrap anything in single quotes, it becomes an atom. It can also have spaces in it.

If you put an underscore at the front, you get an anonymous variable. It ends at the first space or operator.

If you are getting "Singleton variable" warnings, it is usually one of two things.

Beginners often mean to write `'Bob'` but write `Bob` instead (without the single quotes).

You are defining a predicate and you forget to use one of the variables in it. You either have to make it an anonymous variable, `_Bob`, if you really don't care about it, or you find where in the predicate you were supposed to use it.

Comment: Hey. That's really a lot of useful information. I first wrote the names without quotes, and I received a "Singleton variable" error for every  instance. I searched for a solution and found this one. Any idea what a Singleton var error is?

Comment: A singleton variable occurs only once in a rule. This means, the value of that variable is not relevant at all (the variable can have any value). In most cases, this is not what was intended and you get a warning.

Comment: Btw, don't forget that "Frank" is a variable, so defining `man(Frank)` makes the query `man(jackie)` true.